# pygame - Bullet sprite wrong offset from the ship angle (Vectors2)

Tags: python, pygame

There seems to be a weird offset when the bullets are shot from the ship in certain angles while the ship is moving. Also if the ship is shooting in the same direction is heading then the bullet speed is lower.
I tried to work with some SO answers and that's what I came up with:

```
import sys
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
vec = pygame.math.Vector2

pygame.init()
FPS = 60
fps_clock = pygame.time.Clock()
WIDTH = 800
HEIGHT = 800
DISPLAY = pygame.display.set_mode((WIDTH, HEIGHT))
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

MAX_SPEED = 7

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """This class represents the Player."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Set up the player on creation."""
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((70, 50), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.draw.polygon(self.image, (50, 120, 180), ((35, 0), (0, 35), (70, 35)))
        self.original_image = self.image
        self.position = vec(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.position)
        self.vel = vec(0, 0)
        self.acceleration = vec(0, -0.2)  # The acceleration vec points upwards.
        self.angle_speed = 0
        self.angle = 0

    def update(self):
        """Update the player's position."""
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.angle_speed = -2
            player.rotate()
        if keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.angle_speed = 2
            player.rotate()
        # If up is pressed, accelerate the ship by
        # adding the acceleration to the velocity vector.
        if keys[K_UP]:
            self.vel += self.acceleration
        if keys[K_SPACE]:
            player.shoot()
        # max speed
        if self.vel.length() > MAX_SPEED:
            self.vel.scale_to_length(MAX_SPEED)

        self.position += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.position

    def rotate(self):
        # rotate the acceleration vector
        self.acceleration.rotate_ip(self.angle_speed)
        self.angle += self.angle_speed
        if self.angle > 360:
            self.angle -= 360
        elif self.angle < 0:
            self.angle += 360
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.original_image, -self.angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)

    def wrap_around_screen(self):
        """Wrap around screen."""
        if self.position.x > WIDTH:
            self.position.x = 0
        if self.position.x < 0:
            self.position.x = WIDTH
        if self.position.y <= 0:
            self.position.y = HEIGHT
        if self.position.y > HEIGHT:
            self.position.y = 0

    def shoot(self):
        # create and add missile object to the group
        missile = Missile(self.rect.center, self.acceleration, player.acceleration.as_polar()[1])
        all_sprites.add(missile)
        missiles.add(missile)


class Missile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """This class represents the bullet.
     A missile launched by the player's ship.
     """

    def __init__(self, position, direction, angle):
        """Initialize missile sprite.
         Take the position, direction and angle of the player.
         """
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 10], pygame.SRCALPHA)
        self.image.fill(BLUE)
        # Rotate the image by the player.angle
        self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.image, angle, 1)
        # Pass the center of the player as the center of the bullet.rect.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=position)
        self.position = vec(position)  # The position vector.
        self.velocity = direction * 50  # Multiply by desired speed.

    def update(self):
        """Move the bullet."""
        self.position += self.velocity  # Update the position vector.
        self.rect.center = self.position  # And the rect.

        if self.rect.x < 0 or self.rect.x > WIDTH or self.rect.y < 0 or self.rect.y > HEIGHT:
            self.kill()


all_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
player = Player()
all_sprites.add(player)
missiles = pygame.sprite.Group()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    player.wrap_around_screen()
    all_sprites.update()

    DISPLAY.fill(BLACK)
    all_sprites.draw(DISPLAY)
    pygame.display.set_caption('angle {:.1f} accel {} accel angle {:.1f}'.format(
        player.angle, player.acceleration, player.acceleration.as_polar()[1]))
    pygame.display.update()
    fps_clock.tick(FPS)**
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly want to have your missiles start with the velocity of the launching ship (in addition to some speed in the direction the ship is facing).

You might replace the `direction` argument to `Missile.__init__` with a `velocity` parameter that you save directly as `self.velocity` (with no multiplication). The `Player.shoot` method can then be modified to pass an appropriate value that takes both the ship's orientation and velocity into account:

```
def shoot(self):
    # create and add missile object to the group
    missile = Missile(self.rect.center,
                      self.velocity + 50 * self.acceleration,     # new value here!
                      player.acceleration.as_polar()[1])
    all_sprites.add(missile)
    missiles.add(missile)
```

You might want to use a smaller multiple of ship's the acceleration vector, rather than the `50` I copied from your current code, since it won't be the only component of the missile's velocity any more.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem there is that `.rotozoom` uses the angles in counter-clockwise, while  the `.as_polar` vector method returns the angle in clockwise direction (one might expect `.as_polar` to yield an anti-clockwise angle, given what was learned in past math classes, but the Y axis on Surfaces points downwards, while math classes usually had Y pointing upwards).

TL;DR: You just have to invert the angle passed in the call to rotozoom:

```
self.image = pygame.transform.rotozoom(self.image, -angle, 1)
```

You probably will also want to swap the width X height of your missile:

```
self.image = pygame.Surface([10, 4], pygame.SRCALPHA)
```